# Twiter api.GetFriends sometimes doesn't work

Tags: python, api, twitter

I want to build a complex network of twitter followers.
I'm using the function `api.GetFriends` :

```
 def get_friend_list_by_user (user, api) :
        friends_lists = api.GetFriends(repr(user.id))
        return friends_lists
```

The problem is that for the same twitter users, sometimes it works and sometimes doesn't.
When I'm debugging it, 
the code is dead at that part on the `api.py`:

```
   if enforce_auth:
            if not self.__auth:
                raise TwitterError("The twitter.Api instance must be authenticated.")

            if url and self.sleep_on_rate_limit:
                limit = self.CheckRateLimit(url)

                if limit.remaining == 0:
                    try:
                        stime = max(int(limit.reset - time.time()) + 10, 0)
                        logger.debug('Rate limited requesting [%s], sleeping for [%s]', url, stime)
                        time.sleep(stime)
                    except ValueError:
                        pass

        if not data:
            data = {}
```

The `stime` value is 443.

Comment: this *looks* like python-twitter syntax, can you confirm that's the library you are using (there are several Python libraries for Twitter). Are there specific users this fails for? are you saying you just get stuck in sleep, or is something else happening? Any HTTP response code?

Comment: I'm using - import twitter, There are no specific users that it fails for,                                                                          I don't know what going on after the sleep, but on the last running the sleeping value was more the 600, so it slept for more than 10 min. I didn't understand the question about the HTTP

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough information here to debug this fully right now, can you share a more complete code sample that might be reproducible locally (obviously without your application keys)